# Assets plugin not working at all

Tags: assets, module

I have installed the Assets plugin but it is not working at all. It is installed on a linux server with php 5.3.17, Expression Engine 2.6.1 and Assets 2.1.4. I have set the correct upload directories in the basic file manager which is supplied with EE itself. When I want to update the indexes of the Assets plugin, nothing happens. It does, however, uses the following http headers:

A POST from jquery to index.php with the callstack:

- jquery.js:177
- jquery.js:171
- jquery.js:162
- settins.min.js:1
- jquery:86
- jquery.js:78

The response tot that is a HTTP 302 to the location admin.php. Next a GET from /index.php with, again, a HTTP 302 response to admin.php?S=0&D=cpC=homepage. After that, a GET request is made to the forementioned page and a HTTP 200 is returned.

The same requests are made when trying to upload a new file from the Assets plugin. Also, the Upload Files button is disabled. After removing the disabled tag and trying to upload a new file, the three forementioned requests are made with the same response and a javascript alert with the message "Could not upload the file - server returned an unexpected response. Please check the server settings.".

I have reinstalled the module, checked all the required file chmod attributes and session/cookie settings. but to result.

Answer (score 3):

Generally when this happens it’s because either your system is off, or your .htaccess file intercepting Assets’ Ajax requests.

If it’s the latter, you can try adding this to system/expressionengine/config/config.php:

```
$config['assets_site_url'] = "/index.php";
```

Assuming you don’t have a .htaccess redirect that forces “index.php” out of the URL, that should help Assets’ Ajax requests bypass your main index.php redirect.

If you *do* have a redirect that forces index.php out of the URL, then try modifying your main index.php redirect to include this line before the `RewriteRule` line:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^ACT= [NC]
```

And also change your `RewriteRule` line to this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

(Notice the ‘`.+`’ rather than ‘`.*`’.)

Comment: It is a brand new installation so I'm guessing it is the .htaccess file. The file does however forced index.php out of the url:

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
        RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: In that case, updated my response with more info for you.